# Memory Consumtion is very highy on wp7 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, silverlight-toolkit

I am testing my wp7 app and it taking 85MB on Peak memory that is very near to 90MB Limit by Microsoft. How I can reduce that memory consummation.

In my application. I have one panorama page and 3 4 other pages. On panorama page I am loading contacts and showing in my long-list selector. I checked on profile it showing some warnings on Navigation. 
How To Catter That. What is Best Practices in That Scenario.

=== UPDATE ===

1. Should I Empty My Listbox Mean Assign Null As Itemsource on OnNavigatedFrom Event
2. Call GC.Collect() On OnNavigatedFrom Event
3. In the OnNavigatedTo, I manually calls NavigateService.RemoveBackEntry() to remove the page from backstack and then call GC.Collect()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that using a Panorama is extremely expensive memory-wise and ended up switching to a Pivot.  If you have that option, it may be your best bet.  Not sure if there are any real answers here, but here is a thread where this issue is discussed.

[Panorama Memory Usage](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/0d5f8090-ce90-4aab-a6e9-d716c1aacab6)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Best_practice_tips_for_delivering_apps_to_Windows_Phone_with_256_MB) are some tips, which may be interesting for you from tip #5.

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](http://windowsphone7developerguide.blograby.com/resource-management-and-performance/) for read a good article to explain lot off good practices for windows phone. (for limit memory usage too ^^)